# What's the purpose of the MessageProducer and destination?

Tags: jms

It seems like you can only create one `MessageProducer` for one `Destination` in JMS, but why can you pass a `Destination` on the `send()` method? Is it possible to use one `MessageProducer` to send to several `Destination`?

For example:

```java
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(Queue, Queue2);
messageProducer.send(Queue, objectMessage);
messageProducer.send(Queue2, objectMessage2);
```

Comment: Or is there a way to create a temporary producer?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that you can pass Null as a destination on creating. Your answer is awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use one `MessageProducer` to send to several `Destination`. What you want is called an "anonymous" producer.

When you create your `MessageProducer` instance simply pass `null` for the `Destination`, e.g.:

```
private MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(null);
```

This is detailed in the [JavaDoc for `javax.jms.Session`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createProducer-javax.jms.Destination-).

Then specify the `Destination` when sending your messages, e.g.:

```
messageProducer.send(Queue, objectMessage);
messageProducer.send(Queue2, objectMessage2);
```

See more in the [JavaDoc for `javax.jms.MessageProducer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#send-javax.jms.Destination-javax.jms.Message-).